# Brew installed mysql stopped and says Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock

Tags: mysql

I believe my installation of mysql is corrupted (yes I tried reinstalling it)

when I execute `brew services mysql start` it starts and then stops right away

when I execute `mysql_secure_installation`, the terminal had me set a password the first time, and now it asks me to enter it so I do and it responds with `Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)` even if the password is correct.

If I run `nano /tmp/mysql.sock`, I can see that it is an empty text file.

anyone know how I can fix this so I can successfully run mysql and connect to it?

Error Log:

```
2023-08-04T18:45:22.790829Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011011] [Server] Failed to find valid data directory.
2023-08-04T18:45:22.790930Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2023-08-04T18:45:22.790959Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-08-04T18:45:22.791235Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.33)  Homebrew.
2023-08-04T18:45:22.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/NYITM-ROTHMAN.pid ended
2023-08-04T18:45:28.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/NYITM-ROTHMAN.err'.
2023-08-04T18:45:28.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
2023-08-04T18:45:29.238655Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.33) starting as process 49572
2023-08-04T18:45:29.242351Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2023-08-04T18:45:29.266905Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011011] [Server] Failed to find valid data directory.
2023-08-04T18:45:29.267031Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2023-08-04T18:45:29.267086Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-08-04T18:45:29.267383Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.33)  Homebrew.
2023-08-04T18:45:29.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/NYITM-ROTHMAN.pid ended
2023-08-04T18:45:33.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/NYITM-ROTHMAN.err'.
2023-08-04T18:45:33.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
2023-08-04T18:45:33.426323Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.33) starting as process 49704
2023-08-04T18:45:33.429780Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2023-08-04T18:45:33.453007Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011011] [Server] Failed to find valid data directory.
2023-08-04T18:45:33.453128Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2023-08-04T18:45:33.453161Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-08-04T18:45:33.453458Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.33)  Homebrew.
2023-08-04T18:45:33.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/NYITM-ROTHMAN.pid ended
2023-08-04T18:45:39.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/NYITM-ROTHMAN.err'.
2023-08-04T18:45:39.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
2023-08-04T18:45:39.878293Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.33) starting as process 49836
2023-08-04T18:45:39.881788Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2023-08-04T18:45:39.905535Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011011] [Server] Failed to find valid data directory.
2023-08-04T18:45:39.905618Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2023-08-04T18:45:39.905642Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-08-04T18:45:39.905912Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.33)  Homebrew.
2023-08-04T18:45:39.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/NYITM-ROTHMAN.pid ended
2023-08-04T18:45:43.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/NYITM-ROTHMAN.err'.
2023-08-04T18:45:43.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
2023-08-04T18:45:44.067227Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.33) starting as process 49970
2023-08-04T18:45:44.073169Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2023-08-04T18:45:44.097093Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011011] [Server] Failed to find valid data directory.
2023-08-04T18:45:44.097182Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2023-08-04T18:45:44.097208Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-08-04T18:45:44.097468Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.33)  Homebrew.
2023-08-04T18:45:44.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/NYITM-ROTHMAN.pid ended
2023-08-04T18:45:50.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/var/mysql/NYITM-ROTHMAN.err'.
2023-08-04T18:45:50.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/var/mysql
2023-08-04T18:45:50.493887Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.33) starting as process 50108
2023-08-04T18:45:50.497355Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2023-08-04T18:45:50.521155Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011011] [Server] Failed to find valid data directory.
2023-08-04T18:45:50.521242Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2023-08-04T18:45:50.521265Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2023-08-04T18:45:50.521536Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.33)  Homebrew.
2023-08-04T18:45:50.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/var/mysql/NYITM-ROTHMAN.pid ended
```

Comment: Perhaps you want to review the MySQL server error log to see why it "stops right away".

Comment: @mustaccio yes I added the last 50 lines of the error log to the question

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear: "Failed to find valid data directory". Did you check if it exists and has correct permissions?

Comment: @mustaccio I did check and it does exist but I also copied the data directory off of a docker container which was just the default community docker container and used that as the data directory and that did not change anything.